# animation in corona

Tags: coronasdk

how can i perform animation on my moving object....
and how can i control collisions when some of objects are allowed to collide and some not...i,m beginner to corona and coding as well ...i look all the examples i know there r answers of my questions but i cant understand that properly...so any one help me??

Comment: these are two separate questions, it might be better to ask them as separate questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Corona when you create a Physics body you can specify the body type: static, kinematic, and dynamic.

Static bodies don't move, and don't interact with each other; examples of static objects would include the ground, or the walls of a pinball machine.

Dynamic bodies are affected by gravity and collisions with the other body types.

Kinematic objects are in-between Dynamic and Static bodies but doesn't response to gravity

For more information check these links: http://developer.anscamobile.com/content/game-edition-physics-bodies and http://developer.anscamobile.com/reference/index/physicsaddbody

Answer (score 0):

By "animation" I'm going to assume you mean that the graphic changes. In that case you should use a Spritesheet:
http://developer.anscamobile.com/reference/sprite-sheets

As for collisions, there again I'll make an assumption because your question is a little vague. I interpret your question as wondering how to setup collisions where some objects don't collide with each other, and for that you want to set category and mask bits:
http://developer.anscamobile.com/content/game-edition-collision-detection#Collision_categories_masking_and_groups

Comment: thanx sir ! i'm working on your precious suggestions ... and they are very helpful for me...

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy to make a animation by using corona sdk.If using sprite sheet animation  u have use this link http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/newSprite.html.